# How to get a list of messages in @RabbitListener?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring AMQP @RabbitListner :-

```
class MyConsumer {

@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")
  public void handleMessage(Message message){
    doSomething(message)
  }
}
```

How can I make the RabbitListener get a **List<Messages>** instead of a single message, perhaps according to the prefetch count or some other similar config?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 2.2, the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` has a new `consumerBatchEnabled` property which batches up messages according to the `batchSize` and `receiveTimeout` properties. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#receiving-batch

A "short" batch will be delivered if there is a timeout before `batchSize` is reached.